# how to get .sample, if sample exists then get another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting 5 samples (randoms) from a List, using:

```
list = List.all.sample(5)
list.each do |list|
 list.statuses.create(:user_id => @user.id)
end
```

in my Status model I have:

```
validates :list_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

that validates that the list_id is unique for the user. 
However what happens is that it it gives 5 samples, and if one of those are present in statuses it doesn't save.

What I'd like to accomplish though is that it goes and finds a new list, so I always end up with 5 samples, instead of say 3-4 because it got 2 random duplicates.

Comment: `List.all.sample(5)`: you call the method `.sample` on an Array, array containing ALL List records of your DB. You might want to just grab 5 random List record in your DB, not grab all of them and then select 5 of them randomly. (performance gain)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I'm not sure how you do that, would you be able to show me. I'd love to learn it

Comment: Sure, I will need the name of your DB system (MySQL? PostgreSQL? each DB system has its own random function). Also, I don't fully understand your problem, can you add more informations about your relations please? (I guess List `has_many :statuses`, but what about User?)

Comment: @sja Are you saying that sometimes List.all.sample(5) returns five results but some of those are really the same element (i.e., two Lists with the same id)?

Comment: @MrYoshiji it's postgresql.  User has many statuses, asw-well. What's going on is I have a large number of Lists, they get sent as a POST request through an API. What I am trying to do is record which list id that gets sent for the specific user, so that when they do it again the same list id doesn't get sent. But a new random 5.

Comment: @Coenwulf not precisely as I have a validation in the status it doesn't get saved. But if I ask for a sample(5) I might only get 3 list items saved to the db, because if the 2 other samples where present, the db wont save it. I'm trying to figure out how to check if the list id is not in list.statuses if so, then add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is record which list id that gets sent for the specific user, so that when they do it again the same list id doesn't get sent. But a new random 5.

This should do it:

```
specific_user = User.find(params[:id])
lists = List.order('random()') # This random() is a PostgreSQL function!
lists = lists.where('id NOT IN (?)', specific_user.lists.pluck(:id).presence || -1) # exclude the list of the specific_user
lists = lists.limit(5) # limit to only 5 records
lists.each do |list|
 list.statuses.create(:user_id => specific_user.id)
end
```

Comment: only problem I'm having is that where I need to check that the list_id is not present is in the table called

Status. Status looks like this:
user_id | list_id 
and adds the user id and the list they posted. If I write current_user.statuses.pluck(:id) it will look at the current_user id will it not, instead of the list_id ?

Comment: You can pluck the `list_id` attribute of the Status records. (`current_user.statuses.pluck(:list_id)`)

Comment: yeah I figured, and gave you the right answer. Thanks for being awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

First filter out the duplicates, then sample from the remainder. So if `User` have a `has_many :lists` you could do something like:

```
(List.all - @user.lists).sample(5)
```

The `has_many` could be `through :statuses`.